# Count Unique Column Strings and Compare with Another Column

Tags: business-objects

So, I'm new to BO Web Intelligence, so I'll try to explain my problem. I created a simple table below to represent my report. "Tom Smith" is a section break, which is followed by Ann Marie, etc. There is also a break on "Name", which represents clients. Client names are listed more than once since each has multiple "goals" and each goal was touched multiple times (time entered working on goals).

Basically, I want to find all the unique goals for each client in the "Goal" column of the report and see if there is a match in the "GoalTime" column. Goals in the "GoalTime" column are supposed to be the same goals as the "Goal" column, so if there is a goal that doesn't match, or an extra goal, this needs to be flagged and counted to produce totals, percentages, etc.

Is there a way to only display unique values for each client in "Goal"? I know there are ways of playing with the query, universes, filters, etc, to try to create the goal column so that only one goal type is displayed, but I'm looking for a simpler formula-based solution. I'm hoping there is some creative use of a "unique" or "distinct" function, or a creatve way of using "match" to achieve this, which can then be combined with flags to create a count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Tom Smith:

Name:                Goal:               GoalTime:               

Tim                Buy a House          Buy a House                 
Tim              Find Employment      Find Employment              
Tim               Buy a House           Buy a Car                  
Tim              Find Employment      Find Employment 

Chris             Find Employment      Find Employment
Chris              Buy a House           Buy a Car
Chris               Buy a Car           Buy a House
Chris               Buy a Car            Buy a Car

Ann Marie: 

Name:             Goal:              GoalTime:    

Tom             Buy a House          Buy a Car
Tom          Find Employment      Find Employment
```

Comment: So how would you want Chris' section to be displayed, since there are two GoalTime values for the one "Buy a Car" goal?

Comment: Thanks for responding. If possible, I would like each goal only displayed once, so for Chris, the "Buy a Car" goal would only appear once.

Comment: So I tried a formula like =Count([Goal]) In Section but all the goals are labelled "1" because of context since "Buy a House" and "Find Employment" are both unique, but show multiple times because each goal was "touched" multiple times. I also tried using =If([Goal])=Previous ([Goal]) Then 0 Else 1 which doesn't work if the same goal repeats again. I was hoping there some way to use "= Previous" but only for unique values?

Comment: I got this to work by separating the columns into separate tables, sorting the goal column alphabetically, then used the =If([Goal])=Previous([Goal]) Then 0 Else 1, and then filtered to only show the 1's.

Comment: You should be able to do it in one table, but I still don't understand how you want it displayed.  For Chris' one "Buy a Car" row, what do you want to see in "GoalTime"?  If it doesn't matter which one of the two you see, you can just use =Max([GoalTime]) to roll it up.

Comment: I suppose how it's displayed will depend on how I determine matches. For now, just filtering to show one of each goal in the two columns so they can be sorted might be fine. This will allow a visual comparison between the two columns to find matches. However, if there's a way to use a "match" function somehow then the display might have to change.

Comment: At this point I don't think there is any easy way to determine whether a goal in the first column (Goal) is also within the second column (GoalTme), within each groupin of caseworker (Tom Smith and Ann Marie). That would probably require some kind of loop which I don't think is possible in Webi...